# System of Equations with Mods and multiple variables

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

I have the following equations:

$$\begin{align}
aex &\equiv J\bmod Q\\
bey &\equiv K\bmod Q\\
cez &\equiv L\bmod Q
\end{align}$$

Normally I'm supposed to already know a, b, c, Q, J, K, and L.  To provide those values here, though, I think would only complicate it.  I'm supposed to solve for e and x, e and y, or e and z.  Yes, they have a wide range of answers and as e changes, so do x,y,z.  I don't necessarily need to know the exact value of e,x,y,z but rather their ranges (or as close as I can get).  The "mod" is throwing me off.  Even finding the range of values (even if specified by an equation) of even one of the e,x,y,z combinations, I think, would be enough for me to understand it.  I'm sorry, I'm not sure I'm familiar yet with the proper terms to describe all this.

Original Equations:
$$\begin{align}
aex\bmod Q = J\\
bey\bmod Q = K\\
cez\bmod Q = L
\end{align}$$

Possible Fourth Equation (if it helps in a given response):
$$\begin{align}
dew\bmod Q = M\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: In your edit of my post I think you altered my equations, and now they don't make sense to me nor does the subsequent answer make sense.  Its like jumping from step 1 to step 3 perhaps, and I don't know what happened at step 2.

Comment: Generally, the correct way of writing what modulo equations is thr way I wrote it with $\equiv$ and $\bmod Q$ on the far right.

Comment: So, just to blatantly confirm.  Considering my equations, shifting the Mod is acceptable to do and harm anything?  And if so, then why do we even need to consider it at all in our simplification? If we can move it around that easily then wouldn't that contradict its value mid simplification?

Comment: I think you are thinking of $\bmod$ as an operation meaning "remainder of," which is partially right. The main reason we put it on the right is to emphasize the fact that we are using a different number system instead of the integers. Addition, subtraction, and multiplication are the same, but we don't have division. We also don't have a sense of less than or greater than, but we do have a sense of equivalent to. We also only have the numbers from $0$ to $n-1$ in $\bmod n$. There are other differences (square roots, polynomials, exponents, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of division, consider multiplying by the inverse. For instance, solve $ax=b$ by multiplying both sides by $a^{-1}$ (where $a^{-1}a=1$ instead of dividing both sides by $a$. In the the real numbers, there is no difference between the two operations, but there is no division in modular arithmetic, so you have to multiply by the inverse.

Say you wanted to solve $2x\equiv 3\bmod5$. You cannot divide, so you have to solve $a^{-1}a\equiv1\bmod5$ for $a^{-1}$. Luckily, [there are some pretty good methods of doing so](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiplicative-inverse-under-modulo-m/). I won't go too much into it here. Anyway $2^{-1}\equiv3\bmod5$, so we can go back to our equation and mutliply both sides by $3$.
$$(3)2x\equiv(3)3\bmod5\implies x\equiv9\equiv4\bmod5$$
In your case, you can rewrite your equations in terms of $e$ and some constants, which is as good as you can do because you have four variables and three equations.

$$\begin{align}
x &\equiv a^{-1}e^{-1}J\bmod Q\\
y &\equiv b^{-1}e^{-1}K\bmod Q\\
z &\equiv c^{-1}e^{-1}L\bmod Q
\end{align}$$

Comment: I don't get it. a to the power of -1 is supposed to equal "one divided by a where the a is to the power of 2". At least per the reminder research I just did. Or would adding a fourth equation make more sense to explain it? Or is the a to the power of negative one just a way of saying "modular inverse of a" or something...?

Comment: $a^{-1}$ is the modular inverse. It is the solution to $a^{-1}a\equiv1\bmod Q$.

Comment: So, you're saying, for the first equation as an example, "x equals the modular inverse of a (mod Q) times the modular inverse of e (mod Q) times J, all mod Q"?

Comment: @Mine Yes. Because of how modular arithmetic works, you can either multiply them all together and then find the remainder or find the remainder after each multiplication.